# how do I use java 8 streams groupingby to calculate average with filters

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to calculate the average of a List of objects that I'm streaming.
The objects have:

```
ClassX.id
ClassX.name
ClassX.value
ClassX.startTime
ClassX.endTime
```

The objects must be grouped by `ClassX.name` and having the average calculated using `ClassX.value`.

Each object streamed represents either an **start** or **end** of a transaction.
Start transactions has `ClassX.endTime == null`.
End transactions has `ClassX.startTime == null`.
End transactions has `ClassX.name == null`

The value to be aggregated is within the **start** object, but it must be summed to the average **only if the stream also process the corresponding end object of the transation.**

Here's what I have so far(based on the suggestion of **Andreas**):

```java
List<ClassX> classXList = ...

Map<String, Double> average = classXListStrings.stream()
        .map(ClassX::new) //convert to ClassX(the input list is actually String)
        .filter(x -> x.getName() != null) //avoid null entries for getName
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClassX::getName, Collectors.toList()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        // skip group if no end transaction exists
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getStartTime() != null))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        // only average values of start transactions
                        .filter(x -> x.getEndTime() == null)
                        .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(ClassX::getValue))
        ));
```

Is there a way to maybe store the objects streamed into a data structure and then aggregate the value only if the pair of objects begin/end transaction are streamed based on a filter?

Comment: How do you determine whether the object is either a start or end?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention this:

The class also has ```ClassX.startTime``` and ```ClassX.endTime```.
Start objets has **endTime == null**.
End objects has **startTime == null**.

Comment: *"The objects must be grouped by `ClassX.name`"* and *"End transactions has `ClassX.name == null`"* and *"only if the stream also process the corresponding end object of the transation"* means that nothing *can* be processed, because no group will have an end transaction. How do you match up start and end transactions to know whether a start transaction can be processed? Your rules don't work. **Rethink what you are asking for.**

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to associate one object in a stream with another that appears later.

One solution is run through the list twice: First you find the end transactions, collecting them to a set. Then you process the list again, computing the averages.

```
List<ClassX> inputList = ...

Set<String> endSet = inputList.stream()
    .filter(o -> o.endTime != null)
    .map(o -> o.id)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Map<String, Double> average = inputList.stream()
    .filter(o -> o.startTime != null && endSet.contains(o.id))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            o -> o.name, 
            Collectors.averagingDouble(o -> o.value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```java
List<ClassX> classXList = ...

Map<String, Double> average = classXList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClassX::getName, Collectors.toList()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        // skip group if no end transaction exists
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getStartTime() == null))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        // only average values of start transactions
                        .filter(x -> x.getEndTime() == null)
                        .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(ClassX::getValue))
        ));
```

Comment: I'm getting nullPointer on the first collect.
Reason: ```ClassX::getName``` might be null for end transactions. End transactions might have only ```ClassX.id``` and ```ClassX.endTime```.

I have updated my code on the question. With that, I am able to calculate the average for the names, but it is still considering objects with not endTime, which should be discarded.

Any suggestion?

Comment: @svini You changed the code. Ok, the added filter check for null name is valid, but you changed the `anyMatch` condition from `== null` to `!= null`. Change it back.

Comment: I changed because it will return empty using ```== null```: {}.

using ```!= null``` it will return the average of all entries, when in fact it should return the average only for the transactions that have start and end. In this case it's considering entries that have only start too.

Comment: @svini If all end-transactions have null name, and you group by name, then no group will have an end-transaction, so all groups are excluded because of your requirement that they have an end-transaction. The code it simply following *your* rules, so if the rules are flawed, then the code is flawed. Only you know the data, so there is not much we can do. Re-think your rules, then update the code with the actual rules, and ask a new question if you still have trouble. *This* question has been answered.

Comment: make sense @Andreas, I should have written about having ```ClassX.getName() == null``` for end transactions. I updated the description accordingly.